# Joda Time: Finding which days are in a period

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

I have two DateTime variables:  `DateTime begin, DateTime end`, now I want to "walk trough" the period between these dates and determine date by date if that specific date is a monday, tuesday, etc... (Giving the days a number from 1 to 7).

I can't seen to figure out how to walk through the period date by date...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something along the lines;

```
for (DateTime current = begin; current.isBefore(end); current = current.plusDays(1)) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Using this combined with current.getDayOfWeek() nailed it! Tnx!

Answer (score 1):

This should work i guess

```
    ArrayList<Integer> days = new Arraylist<Integer>();
    while(begin.isBefore(end)){
        days.add(begin.getDayOfWeek());
        begin.plusDays(1);
    }
```